# How can I save data from form in base?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am study python and Django now. I don't understand, why my form doesn't save and haven't any errors.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
 class TelegramSettings(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            User,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='TelegramSettings',
  
        )
        bot_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        bot_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        bot_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.bot_name}: {self.bot_token}'
```

**Form:**

```
class TelegramSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TelegramSettings
        fields = ['bot_name', 'bot_address', 'bot_token']

        labels = {
            'bot_name': 'Имя бота',
            'bot_address': 'Адрес бота',
            'bot_token': 'Токен'
        }

        widgets = {
            'bot_token': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'size': 30, 'placeholder': '522081070:AAFuXy8ngp32_Cv-sa7a0exdDsfvtraCjVA'}),
            'bot_address': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'size': 30, 'placeholder': '@somename_bot'}),
            'bot_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'size': 30, 'placeholder': 'Для моего канала'}),

        }
```

**View:**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def telegram_settings_view(request):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    saved_data = TelegramSettings.objects.get(user=request.user.id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save(commit=False)
            webhook = bot_setwebhook(form.cleaned_data['bot_token'])
            if webhook:
                bot_deletewebhook(saved_data.bot_token)
                form.save(commit=True)
                context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'ok'}
                return render(request, template_name, context)
            context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'error'}
            return render(request, template_name, context)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'is_valid': form.is_valid()})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # form = TelegramSettingsForm(initial=model_to_dict(saved_data))
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(instance=saved_data)
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }

        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

When I generate POST request from my template, everything is ok, but data not saved in base!
I am looking for my request in connection(from django.db import connection) and can't find it.

*I don't understand, why is not working*

Alternative cod for saving for data is ok:

```
TelegramSettings.objects.update_or_create(
                    user=request.user.id,
                    defaults={
                        'bot_name': form.cleaned_data['bot_name'],
                        'bot_address': form.cleaned_data['bot_address'],
                        'bot_token': form.cleaned_data['bot_token'],
                    }
                )
```

But it is no good, because if I am will add new field, I need add it to my dict

Comment: The correct way to save data using form is `form.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I understand! Thanks a lot!
Why form didn't save data to base? Because I use wrong instance in object form, look old string:

```
form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

**request.user** is wrong instance for this object.
Right instance is object of model TelegramSettings:

```
saved_data, created = TelegramSettings.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=saved_data)
```

Now code know what I need save

**Here is new code of view function:**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def telegram_settings_view(request):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    saved_data, created = TelegramSettings.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=saved_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            if bot_setwebhook(form.data['bot_token']):
                bot_deletewebhook(saved_data.bot_token)
                form.save()
                status = 'ok'
            else:
                status = 'error'
            context = {'form': form, 'status': status}
            return render(request, template_name, context)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'is_valid': form.is_valid()})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(instance=saved_data)
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `save()` with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database.

```
if form.is_valid:
```

form.is_valid is a method so:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

To save it to database use `form.save()` instead of `form.save(commit=True)`.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def telegram_settings_view(request):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    saved_data = TelegramSettings.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            webhook = bot_setwebhook(form.cleaned_data['bot_token'])
            if webhook:
                bot_deletewebhook(saved_data.bot_token)
                form.save()
                context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'ok'}
                return render(request, template_name, context)
            context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'error'}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'is_valid': form.is_valid()})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(instance=saved_data)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

check the save method reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Look 4 rows down, here I try save form.save(commit=True)

without code form.save(commit=False) I got error: 'TelegramSettingsForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: `if form.is_valid:`  Please change this to `if form.is_valid():`

Comment: Thank you, it is resolve my problem with error: 'TelegramSettingsForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data', but data still doesn't save

Comment: please change `form.save(commit=True)` to `form.save()` and remove `form.save(commit=False)`.

Comment: @Riyas Ac
already, still doesn't work. I removed `form.save(commit=False)`(thanks a lot about `form.is_valid():`) and change `form.save(commit=True)` to `form.save()`

Comment: Are you print `request.POST` ??. Please try for is you got value.

Comment: @AlexandrNazarenko add a `breakpoint()` after this line `form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)` and POST the data. Then go to your django server console, the code will stop at the breakpoint line so, run `form.is_valid()` and see if there are errors, if not check if webhook exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
login_required(login_url="/login/")
def telegram_settings_view(request):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    saved_data, created = TelegramSettings.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            bot_deletewebhook(saved_data.bot_token)
            form.save()
            context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'ok'}
            return render(request, template_name, context)
            context = {'form': form, 'is_updated': 'error'}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'is_valid': form.is_valid()})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TelegramSettingsForm(instance=saved_data)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Here not check if `webhook` is exist or not. It already checked in `is_valid`.

Comment: `bot_deletewebhook`  what is this ?? Is a function ??